# Padding both ends of a vector in Scala

Tags: scala

Given vector `v` with odd number of elements, which starts and ends with `0`, I want to pad it with the first non-positive element found while scanning in both directions from its center, as performed by this code snippet:

```
val v      = Vector(0, 3, -1, 4, 1, 4, 0)
val center = v.length/2
val end0   = v.lastIndexWhere(_ <= 0, center)
val end1   = v.indexWhere    (_ <= 0, center)

println(Vector.fill(end0)(v(end0)) ++ v.slice(end0, end1) ++ Vector.fill(v.length-end1)(v(end1)))
```

which produces `Vector(-1, -1, -1, 4, 1, 4, 0)`. Is there a more concise way to do it? Using a mutable collection to represent `v` is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Not really more concise, but you could use `zipWithIndex` and `map` -- just another variant:

```
val (end0, end1) = (v.lastIndexWhere(_ <= 0, center), v.indexWhere(_ <= 0, center))
val (end0_val, end1_val) = (v(end0), v(end1))
v.zipWithIndex map { case (value, ind) => if (ind < end0) end0_val else if (ind < end1) value else end1_val }
```